# Convert JSON String to Object

Tags: iphone, ipad

Trying to convert JSON String into the object

```
NSString *testString = @"OMJ=\"N.A.\"&SPJ=\"N.A.\"&OBJ=\"N.A.\"";

        NSMutableDictionary *tags = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        tags = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[Utility convertJSONStringToObject:testString]];
```

Errror Message!

```
-[__NSCFConstantString objectFromJSONString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance!
```

After using the NSJSONSerialization the retun value for the dictionary JSON is null empty

```
         NSDictionary *JSON =
   [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [@"OMJ=\"N.A.\"&SPJ=\"N.A.\"&OBJ=\"N.A\"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                        options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                         error: nil];
```

What i did wrong in my code. Any one advice me to fix the issue.

@thanks in advance

Comment: You're using a category on NSString without including the category's .m file in your build.

Comment: (Note that you're not showing us the objectFromJSONString invocation that caused the problem.  Even though the exception traceback in the console would have pointed you directly at it.)